# Select last non-empty cell in column A --> Fill down empty cells below in column A, based on last non-empty cell in column C --> Repeat

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, cell

I would like to fill down the last-non empty cell value in Column A in Excel. It should stop filling down once it reaches the count for the last non-empty cell in Column C. Here is an example:

[image: img1]

It should look like this:

[image: img2]

Would like to repeat this for the last non-empty cell;

[image: img3]

This is the closest I've gotten to what I'm looking for, but I don't want to select A2 every time. I would like to select the last non-empty cell in column A each time.

```
Dim lrowc As Integer

lrowc = SavedData.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    SavedData.Range("A2:A" & lrowc).FillDown
```

Comment: Screenshots of code are not permitted here, thus I've rolled back the question to the version where the code was text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the same principle as you are using for column C - find the last used cell in A and then use `FillDown`:

```
Sub x()

Dim lrowc As Long, n As Long

With SavedData 'assume defined somewhere
    n = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last filled cell in A
    lrowc = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'last filled cell in C
    .Range("A" & n & ":A" & lrowc).FillDown
End With

End Sub
```